# Why do I get different results when invoking "which python" command and python -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, path

I am wondering why I get different results when typing those commands in macOS Terminal:

```
melvin: ~ $ which python 
/usr/bin/python  

melvin: ~ $ which python3  
/usr/bin/python3  

melvin: ~ $ python -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS 
 
melvin: ~ $ python3 -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"  
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

My `$PATH` variable contains `/usr/bin` so when invoking `python` or `python3` shouldn't it be looking in this path? It seems to be ok when using `which` command.

Comment: Maybe the ones in `/usr/bin` are links to those other ones.

Comment: Yes that was my thought too. Maybe my macbook is a complete mess: I downloaded various versions of python in different directories. I'd like to clean this up. Thus, I need to understand what's going on :D

Comment: It's not at all unusual for `/usr/bin/` to contain links to programs in other parts of the file system.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is completely normal